# How to get local time in Azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have read file from FTP using logic apps . Once it read the i moved the file to another folder called ProcessedFiles . While moving i just append the Current date and time in File name .

> EX : FileName_yyyyMMddHHmmss

But utc datetime was appended . I can't get the local time .

```
Code : formatDateTime(utcnow(),'_yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

**Note** : Timezone will differ . Need to get dynamically

Answer (score 1):

try convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time')

Answer (score 0):

The use of the utc time is by design of the platform. The reasoning behind it is globally distributed nature of the systems. You can however use Azure functions to convert the time to local time  (Time Zone of the data center where Azure functions is hosted). Refer [Converting UTC to Local Time via Azure Functions and Logic Apps](https://devkimchi.com/2018/02/05/converting-utc-to-local-time-via-azure-functions-and-logic-apps/)